# Acumatica Create Shipment Lock Violation Exception Issue

Tags: exception, process, locking, acumatica

When Creating a Shipment via API in Acumatica, I receive the error

> Another process has updated 'SOOrder' record. Your changes will be lost

The way we create the Shipment is as follows:

1. Add the sales order to the shipment.
2. Save.
3. Clear the Screen.  oScreen.SO302000Clear();
4. Load the created Shipment.
5. Add Shipment details such as Bin Locations, ship qtys, Batch/Serials etc.
6. Save.

The issue happens if the user loads the created shipment in Acumatica right after it has been created. Then, when the API attempts to post the shipment details (Steps 4 to 6), the API throws the error

> PX.Data.PXLockViolationException: Error #90: Another process has updated 'SOOrder' record. Your changes will be lost.

Is there anyway we can avoid that Lock Violation Exception when editing a Shipment that is currently opened in the UI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saving a shipment triggers a long-running, asynchronous operation. You need to wait for this process to complete before you do anything else, by calling GetProcessStatus() and retrying until it is completed. Otherwise, you'll run into concurrency issues with your second update call.

Comment: Looking for something similar to know if my current graph is in the middle of a long running process. I tried looking for GetProcessStatus and didnt see anything (running Acumatica version 5.3) but i did find PXLongOperation.GetStatus and using it like so:  
PXLongOperation.GetStatus(this.UID) == PXLongRunStatus.InProcess   
Is this a similar concept you were referring to?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, This issues appeared again even after implementing GetProcessStatus. I am receiving same error: Error #90: Another process has updated 'SOOrder' record. Your changes will be lost.'.

Comment: @JoseJoya can you update original question with a full code sample which would allow us to replicate the error on a test/demo instance? Please make the code as simple as possible.